# How to store data in redis cache which supports partial search on multiple fields

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a huge collection of objects over a million and each object has around 8 properties. I'm looking for a fast way to store the data in **Redis cache** which can support partial search on any column to support the advanced lookup. I know we can use HashSet for storing and building the Indexes on each property which can result in occupying huge space as we have to create indexes to support partial search.

Object Ex. - 
class Emp{
  ID,
  Name,
  Email,
  Country,
  etc..
}

I should be ablet o search the collection with ID contains ("12") AND Name contains("abc") and Country Contains("Ind");

I may be wrong in thinking here. Please advise

Comment: You may want to try redisearch module which implements free text search https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/index.html if other databases is choice then Elasticsearch might suit well